# Bootstrap: How to create a series of div on one line hiding the overflowing divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site built with bootstrap and I want to create a table with swipeable header using the jquery.dragscroll plugin but preserving the fluid grid built-in bootstrap.

So I want to create the headers of the table, and I am using this HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;width:90%;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px">some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cVfzJ/1/

As we can see in the Fiddle all the divs are visible on two rows, my objective is to have all the divs on a single row (hiding the overflowing divs)

I hope the question is clear

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should have a container for all the `<div>` that has `width` equal to the sum of all `<div>`. Then the parent of this container has to have `overflow: auto`.

If you don't know the total width prior to the render you can use JS to calculate it.

Continuing your example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">

        <!-- Changed from `hidden` to `auto`. -->
        <div style="overflow:auto;width:90%;">

            <!-- This is the div that does the trick: -->
            <div style="width:1200px;">

            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">some content</div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, is working like a charm
(I cannot accept the answer until 15 minutes, so I will wait 3 minutes to accept)