# Resizing two images at the same line on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to put two images at the same line with Bootstrap, using two different columns. I aligned them, used some background color two see the result, etc.

But, when I change the resolution to see the responsive effect, they not resize by equal! the images haven't the same width, but yes, the same height. Does anyone have a guess?

Here is the HTML:

```css
.coresq {
  background-color: #131313;
}

.cordir {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.top-shows {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.top-shows [class^="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row top-shows">
    <div class="col-xs-4 coresq ">
      <img src="img/slogan_part_1.jpg" alt="imagem" class="slogan_l img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 cordir">
      <img src="img/slogan_part_2.jpg" alt="imagem" class="slogan_r img-responsive"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the display reduces, the responsive properties don't resize equally. Shouldn't? Aren't they at the same line?

Comment: What are the images resolutions?

Comment: the first one has 203 X 51
the second has 346X51

Comment: **You can Try This [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16774135/4210935) for different size of images** ;')

Answer (score 0):

One image is using double cols (`xs-8`) than the other (`xs-4`), so when resizing, the smaller column gets eaten.

[Try resizing this external JSFIDDLE with equal cols](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/4/)

(Also, make sure the images are equal size as in the fiddle above)

Comment: Yes Syden, I took off that space!
And, your suggestion make sense, but, the behavior shouldn't com from the row?
Anyway, testing with equal columns don't work yet, cause the images have  different widths, but the same height.

Comment: Yes, it does... One last doubt....
The behavior for resizing shouldn't be done by the row? I'm thinking like a <table> tag but, as I'm seeing, the grids are controlled individually...
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are, .`row` is used to create horizontal groups of columns. Every .container>.row you set, you have 12 grid columns inside to use. The resizing itself it's handled by the columns, hence why col-xs or col-md (different layout breakpoints in case of smaller/bigger viewports).

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider either upvoting or making correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different column sizes.
`col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8`

you need to use same solumn size for both images if you want them to have same width.
`col-xs-6` and `col-xs-6` would be the sizes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have looking about Flex, that can do it, and saw  the new version of bootstrap (4, but still in alpha).
I've reading a lot about, and decided to test. It works! Exactly the way I asked before, with little changes on code.

Well, the custom css is the same, but the Bootstrap is 4 (alpha, for testing) and the HTML is here:

```html
<div class="container">


    <div class="d-flex flex-row">

      <div class="col-xs-4 coresq ">
        <img src="img/slogan_part_1.jpg" alt="imagem" class="slogan_l img-fluid"/>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-8 cordir">
        <img src="img/slogan_part_2.jpg" alt="imagem" class="slogan_r img-fluid"/>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
.
```

PS: I don't know why, but the code on snippet preview is cutting the last div ending the code. There is a single point on finish.